# Python Multiprocessing conflicting adds to List

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using the python `Process` class to have multiple objects work on multiple pictures and then when a given object is done append the picture to a shared list.

However, the result is that if three objects are created I only see one picture in the list at a time. I never remove the pictures from the list. It seems that each `.append()`  of a new pic is removing the previous picture. How would I go about dealing with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Might want to look into using: [16.6.1.2. Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Comment: You might want to post some specific code.  There is not the slightest chance that list.append actually removes something from the list.

Comment: The basic idea with using a queue might go something like this: your processes put their finished work into the queue, and another process pulls them out of the queue and does what ever you want done with the finished work.

Comment: Are you passing just a normal list to each process?

Comment: use `mylist= manager.list()` and pass it to your workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), Python Lists and Dictionaries are thread-safe within the same process.  Perhaps you can dispatch each process a list or dictionary container to store the response of that process and then append these items back to your list in the main process after process.join()?  That way you won't be sharing the same list across multiple processes, but will instead join them after they complete each process.

You can also use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), which is both thread safe and process safe.

Comment: I am pretty new at multi-processing, want to know how do we get returned values from process if i do a p.join().